# Symfony2 twig function template variable

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to add a common twig function that will be called in layout but the result will be specific for each page depending on given parameters.

I don't want to add each parameters in the twig function.

Is there any way to find those parameters?

exemple:

layout.html.twig:

```
{{ my_twig_function() }}
```

list.html.twig

```
{% extends "::layout.html.twig" %}

{% if test is defined%}test is defined{% endif %}
```

myTwigExtension.php:

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        'my_twig_function' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'getParams'),
    );
}

public function getParams()
{

    // here a way to find all parameters passed to the list.html.twig

    return "ok";
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use a macro instead of a function?

Comment: I think i will have the same problem with macro as I want to be able to check every parameters available given by the current controller.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your MyTwigExtension class as a service ?

```
services:
    twig.twig_extension:
        class: Namespace\NameBundle\Twig\MyTwigExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
        arguments: []
```

Comment: Yes I did but I want to use parameters given by each controller without to passing them

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. In my opinion, it's impossible because your function has no access to variables of your page. But with the declaration twig_extension service, you can injected parameters and/or container service and access at your params. Maybe, if you define your page parameters in a config file, that could answer your problem.

Comment: I want to use parameters given by the controller not only static one.
I think I will need to create an event like KernelEvents::VIEW. I cannot use this one because my controller return a Response.
---------
What do you think of overiding FrameworkBundle:Controller:Controller->render and dispatch my custom event?

Comment: I don't know if override Controller class is the best solution, but maybe that implemented a Listener which listen the "onKernelResponse" event (or "onKernelRequest") will be a best response at your problem.

Comment: I already thought of these events but "onKernelRequest" is too early an will probably make me do two time all the request done by the controller. and the "onKernelResponse" is too late the twig is already generated

Comment: Great! I thought that onKernelResponse was called before… I don't see other solution.